# How KStream suppress operator determines the last record of a window?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here is a simple definition of a window with suppress operator:

```
stream
  .groupBy()
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMinutes(30)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(0)))
  .aggregate(...) // implementation of aggregate function
  .suppress(untilWindowCloses(unbounded())
  .toStream()
  // process last event here
  ...
```

So my question is, how suppress operator detects whether an event is the last event of a window? let's imagine, I remove suppress operator:

```
stream
  .groupBy()
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMinutes(30)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(0)))
  .aggregate(...) // implementation of aggregate function
  .toStream()
  ...
```

I understand that for each change to the `KTable`, two events will be generated:

1. A record with `null` value to remove previous record
2. A new record with new value

What I want to do is to remove `suppress` operator and detect the last record myself:

```
stream
  .groupBy()
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMinutes(30)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(0)))
  .aggregate(...) // implementation of aggregate function
  .toStream()
  .filter( /* detect the last record here */ )
```

Is this information exposed in DSL or processor API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is indirectly exposed only. The `suppress()` operator uses a state store to track previously received messages. This allows to compare old/new messages to each other and to decide when to actually emit something.

Note, that a stateless `filter()` cannot achieve that. If you want to understand the details, you would need to read the source code.

The main question though is: why do you want to remove `suppress()` to begin with?

Comment: Mainly because it doesn't spill to disk and we have relatively huge number of unique keys. I would like to implement a custom processor that utilizes a remote disk based database. I want to get the actual "marker"-like message that specifies a specific window is closed and emit some message to down stream operators accordingly.

Comment: I see -- well, `suppress()` will hopefully allow to spill to local disk in the future... It was planned to get implemented but it's not delivered yet... Note though, that there is no "marker" but `suppress()` decides when to emit based on the input data and their timestamps. You would need to re-implement the same logic. The `aggregation()` does not tell you when a window is closed...